# How does multiarch works?

Tags: linux, gentoo

I'm trying to set up a multiarch rootfs for a system which can run both endianess from the same kernel. Of course, I can' t mix libraries of different endianness inside the same program. On top of that, the big endian rootfs is linked to use µClibc with it's dynamic loader whereas the little endian version is linked against glibc.

I have no idea how the well-known split from systems which run both i686 and amd64 *(even is they rarely use different byte order)*.

But my situation look similar in some ways... it means that:

- I can switch to a different system using chroot : (`chroot /tmp/rootfs`)
- statically compiled binaries can be run everywhere ;

²

```
example.c:
int main() {return 200;}
```

²

```
localhost# gcc -static -Ofast $HOME/example.c -o $HOME/example
localhost# $HOME/example
localhost# echo $?
200
localhost# mv $HOME/example /tmp/rootfs
localhost# chroot /tmp/rootfs /example
localhost# echo $?
200
```

So I added the following paths to /etc/ld.so.conf:

```
/tmp/rootfs/lib
/tmp/rootfs/usr/lib
```

and I copied the dynamic loader from the other rootfs: *(µClibc use ld-uClibc.so)*

```
localhost# ln /tmp/rootfs/lib/ld-linux.so.2 /lib/
localhost# ln /tmp/rootfs/bin/zsh5 /bin/
```

ld-linux.so.2 is a static binary, so I can run any dynamically linked library with it.

```
localhost# /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /bin/zsh5
localhost# exit
localhost#
```

It does look nice, but portage's scripts won't be able to work by this way. I can't use binfmt, since it would create a loop because /lib/ld-linux.so.2 have the same architecture than the target.
So I thought the kernel would find and use the right ELF interpreter automatically but it doesn't:

```
localhost# zsh5
/bin/zsh5: No such file or directory
```

I'm still able to run µClibc executables:

```
localhost# busybox
BusyBox v1.22.1 (2014-06-11 08:01:31 UTC) multi-call binary.
BusyBox is copyrighted by many authors between 1998-2012.
Licensed under GPLv2. See source distribution for detailed
copyright notices.

Usage: busybox [function [arguments]...]
   or: busybox --list[-full]
   or: busybox --install [-s] [DIR]
   or: function [arguments]...

        BusyBox is a multi-call binary that combines many common Unix
        utilities into a single executable.  Most people will create a
        link to busybox for each function they wish to use and BusyBox
        will act like whatever it was invoked as.

Currently defined functions:
        [, [[, acpid, addgroup, adduser, adjtimex, ar, arp, arping, ash, awk, base64, basename, bb, bbconfig, bbsh, blkid, blockdev, brctl, bunzip2, bzcat, bzip2, cal, cat, catv, chat, chattr, chgrp, chmod, chown, chpasswd, chpst,
    chroot, chrt, chvt, cksum, clear, cmp, comm, conspy, cp, cpio, crond, cryptpw, cttyhack, cut, date, dd, deallocvt, delgroup, deluser, depmod, devmem, df, dhcprelay, diff, dirname, dmesg, dnsdomainname, dos2unix, du, dumpkmap,
    dumpleases, echo, ed, egrep, eject, env, envdir, envuidgid, ether-wake, expand, expr, false, fbset, fdflush, fdformat, fdisk, fgconsole, fgrep, find, findfs, flash_eraseall, flash_lock, flash_unlock, flashcp, flock, free,
    freeramdisk, fsck, fstrim, fsync, ftpd, fuser, getopt, getty, ginit, grep, groups, gunzip, gzip, halt, hd, hdparm, head, hexdump, hostname, httpd, hwclock, id, ifconfig, ifdown, ifenslave, ifplugd, ifup, init, insmod, install,
    ionice, iostat, ip, ipaddr, ipcrm, ipcs, iplink, iproute, iprule, iptunnel, kbd_mode, kill, killall, killall5, last, less, linux32, linux64, linuxrc, ln, loadfont, loadkmap, login, losetup, lpq, lpr, ls, lsattr, lsmod, lsof,
    lspci, lsusb, lzcat, lzma, lzop, lzopcat, makedevs, man, md5sum, mdev, mesg, microcom, mkdir, mkdosfs, mke2fs, mkfifo, mkfs.ext2, mkfs.reiser, mkfs.vfat, mknod, mkpasswd, mkswap, mktemp, modinfo, modprobe, more, mount,
    mountpoint, mpstat, mt, mv, nameif, nanddump, nandwrite, nbd-client, nc, netstat, nice, nmeter, nohup, nslookup, ntpd, openvt, passwd, patch, pgrep, pidof, ping, ping6, pipe_progress, pivot_root, pkill, pmap, popmaildir,
    poweroff, powertop, printenv, printf, ps, pscan, pstree, pwd, pwdx, raidautorun, rdate, readahead, readlink, realpath, reboot, renice, reset, resize, rev, rm, rmdir, rmmod, route, rtcwake, runlevel, rx, script, scriptreplay,
    sed, sendmail, seq, setarch, setconsole, setfont, setkeycodes, setlogcons, setserial, setsid, setuidgid, sh, sha1sum, sha256sum, sha3sum, sha512sum, showkey, sleep, softlimit, sort, split, start-stop-daemon, stat, strings, stty,
    su, sum, swapoff, swapon, switch_root, sync, sysctl, tac, tail, tar, tee, telnet, telnetd, test, tftp, tftpd, time, timeout, top, touch, tr, traceroute, traceroute6, true, tty, ttysize, tunctl, tune2fs, ubiattach, ubidetach,
    ubimkvol, ubirmvol, ubirsvol, ubiupdatevol, udhcpc, udhcpc6, udhcpd, umount, uname, uncompress, unexpand, uniq, unix2dos, unlzma, unlzop, unxz, unzip, uptime, users, usleep, vconfig, vi, vlock, volname, wall, watch, watchdog,
    wc, wget, which, who, whoami, whois, xargs, xz, xzcat, yes, zcat, zcip
```

So, I don't understand how multiarch systems use the right interpreter library for the right architecture, since it doesn't work, and my understanding is stuck at that point.

Comment: Wait...how could a statically linked program run on two different endiannesses? That doesn't make sense. The machine code for the two arch's would be different.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe : Yeah That's kinda the problem. The machine code is different *(like with Itaniums processor which were able to run i686 programs natively)* *(Many processor architectures are able to run two different endianness as long as only one is kept inside address space)*. It behave as two different architectures where the processor can run both of them. So I can't mix libraries.

Comment: So...ummm...the SAME machine code can run in BOTH modes???? You said you wanted the statically linked programs to run everywhere.

Comment: On my multiarch (by default, I am running Fedora) system it differs which dynamic linker the program is linked to, e.g. a 32-bit program is linked to `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` vs a 64-bit `/lib64/ld-linux-x64-64.so.2`.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe : No showed it : running statically linked programs everywhere is easy since it doesn't rely on any shared object files. I want to be able to run dynamically linked programs from both endianness inside the same rootfs. The architecture doesn't matter : the aim is to set up a multiarch system, and the process look similar on my platforms. I just don't understand the final step, nor I see what"`system it differs which dynamic linker the program is linked to, e.g. a 32-bit program is linked to /lib/ld-linux.so.2 vs a 64-bit /lib64/ld-linux-x64-64.so.2`"brings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it appeared it was a simple hard-coded path problem.

```
localhost# readelf -l /bin/zsh5

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x40f015
There are 9 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                 0x00000000000001f8 0x00000000000001f8  R E    8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

adding this library at this path and`ld-2.19.so`in`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` solved my problem.

So It's probably the first system which is able to run amd64 and mips the same way it can run i686 :).

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, you can only run a binary with the same endianess as the kernel it's running on. If you want to run an armeb (big-endian ARM) binary, you need to have an armeb kernel and if you want to run an armel binary, you need to have an armel kernel. This is true for all CPU architectures that support big- and little-endian modes in Linux (ARM, ARM64, ARC, C6x, PowerPC, MIPS, m32r, microblaze, SH4, xtensa).

There are two ways to get around this, but both have significant downsides as well:

1. You can run *any* binary using [qemu-user emulation](https://wiki.debian.org/QemuUserEmulation). A typical example of this is running an ARM binary on x86, but you can also run a PowerPC little-endian binary on a big-endian ARM kernel or any other combination as long as both the host and the target are supported by qemu. Some things (e.g. rare device drivers) may not work because of missing emulation code in qemu, and in general everything will run slowly, typically a factor of 10 slower than executing the native instructions.
2. You can run a KVM guest in different endianess from the host, provided you have hardware support. This works on some ARM32 (Cortex-A7, A12, A15, A17, but not Cortex-A9 or older) as well as PowerPC and ARM64. The processes of the guest are not visible to the host or vice versa, and you have to set up internal networking and storage for the guest to do anything useful.

Comment: qemu-user-static with binfmt.. That's what I'm using already to run the executables as if they were natively supported. Anyway, I finally found the solution and discovered they were a mysterious path problem thanks to some peoples on IRC. I don't understand why this problem appeared, but I solved it. Otherwise, you can't use KVM on mips32r2.